# TextView programmatically Android

Tags: android, textview, programmatically-created

I have some problems creating a textView programmatically. I don't really know how to solve it.

[image]

The problems are :

-The margin, I don't want my TextView stuck to each other.

-The text is not centered in the drawable like in the title

-I want the messages of Nickname user aligned to the right and the messages of Nick aligned to the left.

For this I have these two functions :

```
private void appendSenderText(String message) {

        TextView msg = new TextView(ChatActivity.this);
        msg.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rectangle);
        msg.setText(message);
        msg.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        msg.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.LEFT);
        params.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
        msg.setLayoutParams(params);
        LinearLayout chat = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chatLayout);
        chat.addView(msg);  
    }

    private void appendReceiverText(String message) {

        TextView msg = new TextView(ChatActivity.this);
        msg.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rectangle);
        msg.setText(message);
        msg.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        msg.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.RIGHT);
        params.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
        msg.setLayoutParams(params);
        LinearLayout chat = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chatLayout);
        chat.addView(msg);  
    }
```

It seems that it is not working. I've also checked that the functions are correctly called.
I noticed that in my XML file for the title, I specified layout_gravity and not gravity.

EDIT : I used ListView as you suggested, everything is working fine but I still have this problem with the text not centered, although I used `msg.setGravity(gravity.CENTER);`
Maybe my drawable has a problem.

Here is the xml file for my rounded rectanngle. That's weird, when I create my Textview in XML file, the text is centered, and when I want to create programmatically, it's not the case.

[image]

Here is the code of my drawable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
     android:startColor="@color/drk_button"
     android:endColor="@color/lgt_button"
     android:angle="90">
   </gradient>

   <corners android:radius="7dip" />

   <stroke
     android:width="1px"
     android:color="@color/drk_button" />
</shape>
```

And here the code where I create the texView.

```
Message message = (Message) this.getItem(position);

        ViewHolder holder; 
        if(convertView == null)
        {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.sms_row, parent, false);
            holder.message = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        holder.message.setText(message.getMessage());
        holder.message.setTextSize(17);
        holder.message.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) holder.message.getLayoutParams();
        if(message.isMine())
        {
            holder.message.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rectangle);
            lp.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
        }
        else
        {
            holder.message.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rectangledest);
            lp.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
        }
        holder.message.setLayoutParams(lp);
        holder.message.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);   

        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: you should definitely use a ListView for chat-like things

Comment: If you are developing a chat application, better use `ListView` and go through some sample chat app codes.

Comment: https://github.com/AlexBarinov/UIBubbleTableView

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I updated your functions and it is working as you want now:

```
private void appendSenderText(String message) {

    TextView msg = new TextView(ButtonsActivity.this);
    msg.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rectangle);
    msg.setText(message);
    msg.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
    msg.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.setMargins(5, 15, 0, 0);
    params.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
    msg.setLayoutParams(params);
    msg.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    LinearLayout chat = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chatLayout);
    chat.addView(msg);  
}

private void appendReceiverText(String message) {

    TextView msg = new TextView(ButtonsActivity.this);
    msg.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rectangle);
    msg.setText(message);
    msg.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
    msg.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.setMargins(0, 15, 5, 0);
    params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
    msg.setLayoutParams(params);
    msg.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    LinearLayout chat = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chatLayout);
    chat.addView(msg);  
}
```

You have to set `TextView` gravity to position the text inside the `TextView` and set gravity in the parent `LinearLayout` to set the position of the `TextView` inside the `LinearLayout`.

Notice that I'm using a `LinearLayout` instead of a `FrameLayout`.

Answer (score 1):

Use custom listviews to populate chat lines.

To make the chat text at center add this line.

```
msg.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

I believe your frame layout brings the textviews close each other.

I recommend you to use ListView with custom adapter to populate chat lines. Its easy to add the chat lines and update the view in ListViews. [check this link](http://adilsoomro.blogspot.in/2012/12/android-listview-with-speech-bubble.html) . it will give you a basic idea.