# Textview gravity in custom ViewGroup

Tags: android, textview, gravity, viewgroup

I have a custom view that extends `ViewGroup` and I don't know why but I can't center the text of my `TextView` vertically.

This is how I do it:

```
TextView myTextView = new TextView(mContext);
myTextView.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFF9900);
myTextView.layout(left, top, right, bottom);
myTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER); // with this, the text is centered horizontally but is still on top. There is plenty of space below
this.addView(myTextView);
```

I have do this a lot of time on `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout`, I should have missed something but what?

Edit:

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {

Point centerOfView = new Point(this.getMeasuredWidth()/2, this.getMeasuredHeight()/2);

Log.d(TAG, "onLayout changed:"+changed+" buttonDiametre:"+buttonDiametre);

for(int n=0; n< this.getChildCount(); n++){
     View v = getChildAt(n);

     if (v instanceof TextView) {

         v.layout(centerOfView.x-buttonDiametre/2, centerOfView.y-buttonDiametre/2, centerOfView.x+buttonDiametre/2, centerOfView.y+buttonDiametre/2);
         ViewGroup.LayoutParams textViewParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

         v.setLayoutParams(textViewParams);


         TextView txt = (TextView)v;
         txt.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        }
 }
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
Log.d(TAG, "onMeasure");

int width = getMeasuredWidth();
int height = getMeasuredHeight();

buttonDiametre =  (int) (this.getMeasuredWidth()/4);
Log.d(TAG, "buttonDiametre:"+buttonDiametre+" getChildCount:"+getChildCount());

for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
    View child = getChildAt(i);

    child.measure(buttonDiametre, buttonDiametre);
}

setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
}
```

With this try to override onMeasure and onLayout, I see no changes except that the text has lost it center horizontal align. The text is now on top left even with setGravity set to center.

Otherwise, my textbox that are in a square form display well on the different positions. I know i have put them in center but i animate them later to get in correct pposition.

Comment: you might need to check your TextView height.

Comment: did you override `onMeasure`?

Comment: No i don't have override onMeasure since it display fine on screen. Is it mandatory ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23990743/textview-programmatically-android

Comment: no its not mandatory, but when you dont do that the results are like yours

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your `TextView` height to `MATCH_PARENT`, then it will center text vertically, too:

```
TextView myTextView = new TextView(mContext);
myTextView.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFF9900);
myTextView.layout(left, top, right, bottom);

ViewGroup.LayoutParams textViewParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
myTextView.setLayoutParams(textViewParams);

myTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER); // with this, the text is centered horizontally but is still on top. There is plenty of space below
this.addView(myTextView);
```

Comment: Thanks for you help but text is still on top

Comment: It means that your custom `ViewGroup` has the same height like `TextView`. By changing `ViewGroup` height, you can change `TextView` height also.

Comment: Can you take a look on my onMeasure and onLayout code ? The TextViews don't fill the screen and i see them where they should be because of background color. The custom view has a bigger size and there is a ImageView as background that take well the full ViewGroup.